# Custom iteration over a JDBC ResultSet

Tags: java, loops, jdbc, resultset, impala

I have a resultset that returns a list of (repeated) names with some sql conditions associated with that name. It is a 2 column resultset. It looks like this:

```
____________________________________
|id                |     data      |
|__________________________________|
|john              | sql1          |
|john              | sql2          |
|adam              | sql1          |
|jack              | sql3          |
|jack              | sql2          |
____________________________________
```

What I'd like is to build a SQL query that looks like this:

```
select *, 'john' as id from table_x where sql1 or sql2
union
select *, 'adam' as id table_x where sql1
union
select *, 'jack' as id from table_x where sql3 or sql2;
```

Is this possible simply by using the res.next() in a while loop and doing some magic there? I thought of using a 2-d array or a Map to first store the resultset and then iterate over that to get this done, but wanted to know if there are any better/easier ways of doing this.

Comment: @Andreas: Can you point me in the right direction regarding checking for change in the value of `id`? Thanks! :)

Comment: Converted comment to answer.

Comment: What is your DB platform?  I assume that sql1, and sql2 are predicates (col_name = value)?

Comment: @slambeth: You're right. They are predicates. I'm using Impala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that impala has a group_concat function, so you could leverage that to illiminate a step.

(table_y being the table that your initial resultset came from

```
select id, group_concat(data) as predicates from table_y group by id;
```

Then simply loop through them:

```
  String sql;  
  while(rs.next()) {
      String rPredicates = rs.getString("predicates").split(",");
      sql = "SELECT *, " + rs.getString("id") + " FROM table_x WHERE "
      sql += rPredicates[0];
      for(int ndx=1; ndx< rPredicates.length; ndx++) {
        sql += " or " + rPredicates[ndx];
      }
      sql += " union ";
    }
```

This is untested, but you get the point.  You could eliminate a few lines by using StringUtils.join or .collapse something simlar.  There are many string utils classes out there.

If you tried hard enough, you might be able to produce this purely with SQL, but this is a bit better at least.

**EDIT:**
I'll one up this, you can supply a seperator to group_concat, so you could possibly execute this SQL to start

```
select id, group_concat(date, ' or ') as predicates from table_y;
```

Then you won't have to assemble the predicates, simply append the whole thing.

Comment: This looks like a good idea! Thanks for your answer :) I will try out both and pick one.

Comment: Holy SQL Batman! That edit was awesome! I already had code to do the union (even before @Andreas' answer). With this query, I do not need to change the code one bit! And to think, all I needed to do was RTFM! :P Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @CodingInCircles A very important piece of information for this solution was the DBMS vendor (Impala). This is a great vendor-specific solution, while my answer will work for all DBMS vendors. *+1 for simple solution.*

Comment: Yes this is pretty specific, so perhaps not desirable for all solutions.  Some other DBMSs have string aggregate functions as well though.  Oracle has one, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's possible.

If you sort the query by `id`, you can use a normal `ResultSet` loop, and check for change to the `id` value. No need for 2D array or `Map`, just a `StringBuilder` for incrementally building the SQL in question.

```
String prevId = null;
StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
while (rs.next()) {
    String id   = rs.getString("id");
    String data = rs.getString("data");
    if (id.equals(prevId)) {
        sql.append(" or ");
    } else {
        if (prevId != null)
            sql.append(" union ");
        sql.append("select *, '")
           .append(id) // may need to SQL escape value
           .append("' as id from table_x where ");
        prevId = id;
    }
    sql.append(data);
}
```

Comment: Using StringJoiner for the  UNION in between might be fun.

Comment: Thank you for this. I will give it a shot and accept it after testing. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will receive a single result set that is the union of all 3 selects.  If you want to categorize by id column, you would simply iterate through result set, and process the current row based on value of id column (for example, use id value as the key into a map).

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I have a resultset already which is the id and data columns. Using that, I want to build the query as shown.

Comment: OK, I think I'm close.  You would build a map with id column value as key and list of data values as values, then use this map to build each select